# Adding a table around the pop-up information in Leaflet

Tags: html-table, popup, leaflet

I want to create a table around the pop-up information in Leaflet. I am using bootstrap for the mark-up. I tried the following code but it didn't work:

```
onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
            layer.on({
                click: function showResultsInDiv() {
                    var d= document.getElementById('tab4');
                    d.innerHTML =  "<table>"
                                      "<tbody>"
                                        "<tr>"
                                          "<th scope="row"><h3>" + feature.properties.name + "</h3></th>"
                                        "</tr>"
                                        "<tr>"
                                          "<th scope="row">" "</th>"
                                        "</tr>"
                                        "<tr>"
                                          "<th scope="row">ID</th>"
                                          "<td>" + feature.properties.id + "</td>"
                                        "</tr>"
                                        "<tr>"
                                          "<th scope="row">X</th>"
                                          "<td>" + feature.properties.x + "</td>"
                                        "</tr>"
                                        "<tr>"
                                          "<th scope="row">Y</th>"
                                          "<td>" + feature.properties.y + "</td>"
                                        "</tr>"
                                        "<tr>"
                                          "<th scope="row">Keten</th>"
                                          "<td>" + feature.properties.keten + "</td>"
                                        "</tr>"
                                        "<tr>"
                                          "<th scope="row">Naam</th>"
                                          "<td>" + feature.properties.name + "</td>"
                                        "</tr>"
                                      "</tbody>"
                                    "</table>";
                }
            }); }
    }).addTo(map);
```

This is what I want:

[image]

This code work but doesn't give me table mark-up:

```
d.innerHTML =  "<h3>" + feature.properties.name + "</h3> ID:" + feature.properties.id + "<br> X-as:" + feature.properties.x + "<br> Y-as:" + feature.properties.y + "<br> Keten:" + feature.properties.keten + "<br> Naam:" + feature.properties.name;
                        $('.nav-tabs a[href="#tab4"]').tab('show');
```

Comment: Can you illustrate via plnkr.co or jsfiddle ?

Comment: Can't make a plunker because it runs on my DB. But i updated my question with a code that works but that doesn't give me the table mark-up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two problems:

- The strings are not being concatenated. If you are going to split strings in this way in JS, use a `+` operator dangling at the end of every line, i.e.:

  ```
  d.innerHTML =  "<table>" +
                   "<tbody>" +
                     "<tr>" +
                       // etc
  ```
- By default, tables in HTML don't have borders. Either assign a CSS class to it, or use inline CSS in your `<table>` tag.